# How to make do-loop conditions "when string does not equal"

Tags: java, do-loops

I want to make my do loop run while the input the user made is not equal to the required letters (a-i) For some reason,even when i input the proper letters, it loops forever.

I've tried using switch cases as well as != inside the comparison.

Here is my code:

```
do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the location of your battleship, starting with the first letter value. Make sure it is from the letters a-i.");
            lL1=in.nextLine();
            if (!lL1.equals("a")||!lL1.equals("b")||!lL1.equals("c")||!lL1.equals("d")||!lL1.equals("e")||!lL1.equals("f")||!lL1.equals("g")||!lL1.equals("h")||!lL1.equals("i")){
                System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again.");
            }//End if statement
}while(!lL1.equals("a") || !lL1.equals("b") || !lL1.equals("c") || !lL1.equals("d") || !lL1.equals("e") || !lL1.equals("f") || !lL1.equals("g") || !lL1.equals("h") || !lL1.equals("i"));
```

My skills in Java are limited but this should work, unless i'm missing something obvious. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Your condition is always true. If  lL1 is "a" for example, then `!lL1.equals("b")` is true, and the whole condition is thus true, since one of them is true and they're combined with a logical `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an operator for each case of the input, you might want to create a list of the accepted answers and then your condition will look like:

`while answer is not in accepted answers, ask another input`

An example would be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> acceptedAnswers = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
String input;
do {
    System.out.println(
            "Please enter the location of your battleship, starting with the first letter value. Make sure it is from the letters a-i.");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
} while (!acceptedAnswers.contains(input));
scanner.close();
System.out.println("Got correct input: " + input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a negation you need AND to join the conditions not OR.

Answer (score 0):

That's because if you *or* some *not-ed* values, they form an *and*.
Let me explain better.

If you input a, then the first is false (because you not it), and the others are true, so the *or* condition make the result be *true*.

You should instead group all the ors and then not it.

e.g.

```
!(lL1.equals("a") || lL1.equals("b") || lL1.equals("c") || lL1.equals("d") || lL1.equals("e") || lL1.equals("f") || lL1.equals("g") || lL1.equals("h") || lL1.equals("i"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    char lL1;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the location of your battleship, starting with the first letter value. Make sure it is from the letters a-i.");
        lL1=scanner.next().charAt(0);

    }while(lL1!='a' && lL1!='b' && lL1!='c' && lL1!='d' && lL1!='e' && lL1!='f' && lL1!='g' && lL1!='h' && lL1!='i');
```

Since you are only getting a single character, you can check that it does not match either [a to i] characters as shown above. This is the shortest way to do so by making the check as the condition of the loop. If it fails then the loop will be called.